# In Navigation, possibility for page as Parent Navigation Item for other pages?

Tags: pencilblue

Through the admin GUI I want to use a page as Parent Navigation Item for a set of other pages. Instead of a Container.

Is there a way to make this possible?

Answer (score 2):

First, you would have to create a plugin that overrides the dropdown template, since Bootstrap doesn't have clickable dropdowns in the navbar by default.

Then you would want the plugin to [override the navigation form](https://github.com/pencilblue/pencilblue/blob/master/plugins/pencilblue/templates/admin/content/navigation/nav_item_form.html#L61) to show the Link field when navItem.type is "container".

Lastly, your plugin would need its own [getBootstrapNav function](https://github.com/pencilblue/pencilblue/blob/master/include/theme/top_menu.js#L165), preferably in a custom service, that would inject the link into the dropdown item.

Comment: Thanks for the help! If I manage to make it work, I'll share the plugin.

By the way, I hope my question is not that poor. It's voted '-1'.